# How to find location of android mobile from another android mobile..?\

Tags: android

i want to develop android apps that are namely A and B. In App A , i will enter phone number and the corresponding phone number must have the app B and receive request from app A to enables the GPS. I have no idea about this because am new to android. can you guys give me some ideas..? thanks in advance

Comment: you can do it by using server client communication i.e. get the location of one user and send it to your server and use GCM or service to get that location

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is untenable because the app will violate all privacy and security norms. It's a different thing if App B keeps periodically pushing out it's location to a server and App A fetches location updates from the server.